# Docker storage driver AUFS vs overlay2

Tags: docker, файловая-система

В чем отличие этих файловых систем? Какую лучше использовать и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В чем отличие этих файловых систем?

[AUFS](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/aufs-driver/) - большая плотность контейнеров, меньшая производительность при работе со слоями.

[overlay2](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-overlay-or-overlay2-storage-driver) - больше дискового пространства, быстрые операции со слоями.

> Какую лучше использовать и почему?

Лучше использовать `overlay2`, так как меньше накладных расходов на работу со слоями (CPU, RAM).

Answer (score 1):

AUFS существует только в Ubuntu/Debian в отличии от overlay2. Является драйвером по-умолчанию для инсталляций Docker CE на Ubuntu/Debian. Для продакшн-сред подходит плохо и не рекомендуется к использованию.
Технически оба драйвера работают похожим образом.